# jQuery + Regex to change CSS of first couple of Words

Tags: jquery, css, regex

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Comment: And what is it you want to do exactly? As it stands, I don't see an actual question here...

Comment: What's the problem ? Also shouldn't you just add a line of CSS instead of adding `<strong>` tags ?

Comment: You have no element with id 'post-toptitle', so your javascriptdoes nothing.

Comment: I edited my post to be more descriptive of the problem. My apologies I thought the title would be descriptive enough.

Comment: `jQuery("#post-toptitle").each` -- I **hate** this line...it means you have repeating ID's...which is BAD! :)

Comment: Try: `me.html( me.text().replace('', '<strong>').replace('"', '</strong>"') );`. If the `"` was only for explanation and you want to target the first two words in a normal sentence, try it this (extremely ugly looking) way:`me.html( me.text().replace('', '<strong>').replace(' ', '</strong>').replace(' ', '</strong>').replace('</strong>', ' ') );`

Comment: @Neograph734 That's a typo. The h1 id should've been 'post-toptitle'.

Comment: @tewathia no I plan on including the " to target the words I want as opposed to always using the first 2 words only. To me it looks like     .replace('', '<strong>') would target every white space, am I wrong?

Comment: `Replace` only targets the first instance of the target string. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6Tz58/2/

Comment: Why have you shown PHP in the part where you've claimed to have shown HTML? Show the *actual (**relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)**) HTML* that the PHP *generates* ('view source' in the browser), and show what you want the HTML to *after* it's been manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to place a `"` to indicate where the `strong` tag should end you can use `replace` twice to solve your problem.

```
me.html( me.text().replace('', '<strong>').replace('"', '</strong>"') );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6Tz58/11/)

(I've also included a (rather ugly, as mentioned previously) way to pick the first two words, even without the `"` placeholder, using just `replace`)

Comment: This is what I've customized the code to: http://jsfiddle.net/6Tz58/9/

Works great in fiddle. In practice here is the output:
`<strong>Please Halp” Me</strong>`

Comment: For some reason the inline " isn't being selected and replaced

Comment: I don't see why that should happen, considering the same code works on jsfiddle. Experiment with other symbols(* or ` instead of ")

Answer (score 0):

You could save the text as a variable then split it at the chosen character (") and replace the text inside the H1. Although note that if there are more than 1 of your chosen character then it fails.

```
var text = $('#post-toptitle').text().split('"');
$('#post-toptitle').html('<strong>'+text[0]+'</strong>' + text[1]);
```

Also - you shouldn't need '.each()' if your selector is an ID since it should be unique.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Tz58/8/